# Dateformat in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the date difference:

```
var dateString='2015-04-07T10:46:25Z';
var dt = new Date(value);
var now = new Date();
var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var utc1 = Date.UTC(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
var utc2 = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var days=Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);//this is 415
```

The result must be in this format: 415d, 03:06:33

What would be the best way to do that? I get date, but time is missing.

Comment: use a lib like moment.js, which greatly simplifies date/time manipulation in JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

    var datetime = new Date("2015-04-07T10:46:25Z");
    var now = new Date();
    if (datetime < now) {
            var diffTime = now - datetime;
        }else{
            var diffTime = datetime - now;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(diffTime / 1000 / 60 / (60 * 24));

        var dateDiff = new Date( diffTime );

         var hour = dateDiff .getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + dateDiff .getHours() : dateDiff .getHours();
         var minute = dateDiff.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + dateDiff.getMinutes() : dateDiff.getMinutes();
         var seconds = dateDiff.getSeconds().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + dateDiff.getSeconds() : dateDiff.getSeconds();

        console.log(days + "d "+ hour  + ":" + minute  + ":" + seconds);
```

Comment: @Simon updated the answer...please use the update one

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **Modulus**

```js
var dt = new Date('2015-04-07T10:46:25Z');
var now = new Date();

var milSecondMil = 1000;
var secondMil = milSecondMil * 60;
var hourMil = secondMil * 60;
var dayMil = hourMil * 24;

var diff = now - dt;

var days = Math.floor(diff / dayMil);

var daysRemainder = diff % dayMil;

var hours = Math.floor(daysRemainder / hourMil);

var hoursRemainder = daysRemainder % hourMil;

var seconds = Math.floor(hoursRemainder / secondMil);

var secondsRemainder = hoursRemainder % secondMil;

var milSeconds = Math.floor(secondsRemainder / milSecondMil);

console.log(days + ' days - ' + hours + ' hours - ' + seconds + ' seconds - ' + milSeconds + ' mil');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way:

```
    var dt = new Date(value);
    var now = new Date();
    var date1_ms = dt.getTime();
    var date2_ms = now.getTime();
    var diff=(date2_ms - date1_ms) / 1000;
    var tm = new Date(null, null, null, null, null, Math.floor(diff % 86400)).toTimeString().split(" ")[0];

    return Math.round(diff / (60 * 60 * 24)) + 'd, ' + tm;
```